# Regex to extract multiple pieces across multiple lines

Tags: regex, zabbix

I am working on making basic Zabbix items for Wazuh. Its not to replace Wazuh, but our techs live in Zabbix and this provides an alert in Zabbix so techs can know something and can go check to Wazuh.

The issue is that Wazuh alerts are multi-line alerts and we need 2 pieces of information.
From the example below, we would like to get:

- (server)
- (level 10) -> 'High amount of POST requests in a small period of time (likely bot).'

I use the following regex:

```
([\r\n].*?)(?:=?\r|\n)(.*?(?:(level 10.*)).*)
```

This will match on level 10 and then I can use group 1 to get the host name (server). But I am unable to get the second part. I can create an item for each level of rule (1-10 for example) and can get host name. But I can not get the alert itself. I read that I need to create individual items for each pience but what I found is that Zabbix does not always grab right piece from alert. Maybe alert 10 is one item captured but host name is from another log entry.

Is there a way to capture all of these in one item using regex in Zabbix?

Thank you. I appreciate all your help.

```
** Alert 1646336311.8104996: - web,appsec,attack,pci_dss_6.5,pci_dss_11.4,gdpr_IV_35.7.d,nist_800_53_SA.11,nist_800_53_SI.4,tsc_CC6.6,tsc_CC7.1,tsc_CC8.1,tsc_CC6.1,tsc_CC6.8,tsc_CC7.2,tsc_CC7.3,
2022 Mar 03 19:38:31 (server) any->/var/log/nginx/access.log
Rule: 31533 (level 10) -> 'High amount of POST requests in a small period of time (likely bot).'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use Javascript in Preprocessing:

```
value1 = value.replace(/.*1.*/g,'Mobile"')
value2 = value.replace(/.*2.*/g,'Mobile"')
finishvalue = value1.concat(value2);
return(finishvalue)
```